# Does the Arduino Uno use a resonator or a crystal for the processor clock?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

The FT232RL had an internal oscillator whereas the 8u2 does not. That means there is a 16mhz crystal next to the 8u2 to allow it. So how is the CPU an Arduino UNO timed?

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be does this (my) specific Arduino UNO have..>br>A note before the 8u2 is responsible for serial/usb and is not the CPU
Quote from AVR datasheet:

```
Clock Sources<br>
The device has the following clock source options, selectable by Flash Fuse bits as shown
below. The clock from the selected source is input to the 
AVR clock generator, and routed to the appropriate modules.<br>
Note: 1. For all fuses "1" means unprogrammed while "0" means programmed.
9.2.1 Default Clock Source
The device is shipped with internal RC oscillator at 8.0MHz and with the 
fuse CKDIV8 programmed, resulting in 1.0MHz system clock. 
The startup time is set to maximum and time-out period enabled. 
(CKSEL = "0010", SUT = "10", CKDIV8 = "0"). The default setting ensures that all
users can make their desired clock source setting using any available programming interface
```

The stock Uno R3 has both a crystal and a resonator. 
The Atmega8U2 uses a crystal; the Atmega328 uses a resonator. 
In addition to being less accurate, the frequency of a resonator is also more temperature sensitive than with a crystal, meaning linear rise vs. parabolic rise (because also crystals are temperature sensitive)
So to programming if you need exact timing get a RTC or similar add on module.
To come back to the start of my short info. I have UNO clones with crystal and others with external resonator. So you see there is no NO or YES..